# Get data from SQL Result

Tags: python, html, css, sql-server

Can someone please help me understand how to select the field value displayed in a sql RESULT? I would want to use that value to run a new a different query.

I'm using Python to connect html, apache and sql server to create a website that will run SQL query and display results. Once I get the result, I would want to use the value of one the column in a new SQL query. Is there a way to do that instead of manually typing the value in a form?

*Code1*: The code below performs a database call that displays the results based on the sql query.

```
# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db1.cursor()

SQLQuery = ("SELECT  I.OpinionID,
                     I.TimeStamp,
                     I.Strategy,
                     I.ExpectedTradingPrice,
                     I.ExpectedDate,
                     I.CPAMAnalyst,
                     I.Conviction,
                     I.Status,
                     N.DebtTicker,
                     N.InstrumentType,
                     N.ExpectedMaturity,
                     N.OrderSize,
                     N.Allocation
                 From [CpamTestAugustTestSteve].[dbo].[NewIssueOpinion] I
                 INNER JOIN [CpamTestAugustTestSteve].[dbo].[NewIssue] N ON I.NewIssueID = N.NewIssueID
                 WHERE N.ExpectedIssueDate >= GetDate()-30
                     AND I.Status = 'Suggested' AND I.Active = 1;")

#Execute the SQL command
cursor.execute(SQLQuery)


#Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.
results=cursor.fetchall()
y = len(results)


print "<br> <br>"
print "<body2>"
print """<form action="http://localhost/NewIssueStatusUpdate.py" method="post">
            <div> <input type="Submit" class= "submitbutton" value="Submit" /> </div> <br> <br>
</form>"""
if  not cursor.rowcount:
    print "<b> <mark> NO RECORDS FOUND!!</mark> </b>"
else:
    print "<TABLE>"
    print "<tablebody>"
    print"<tr>"
    print "<tr><th>S.No</th><th>OpinionID</th> <th>TimeStamp</th> <th>Strategy</th> <th>ExpectedTradingPrice</th> <th>ExpectedDate</th> <th>CPAMAnalyst</th> <th>Conviction</th> <th>Status</th> <th>DebtTicker</th> <th>InstrumentType</th> <th>ExpectedMaturity</th> <th>OrderSize</th> <th>Allocation</th><th>New Status</th>"
    for p in range(y):
        print "<tr><td>%s</td>" %(p+1)
        for q in range(len(results[p])):
            r= results[p][q]   
            print "<td> %s </td>" % (r)
    print "<td><select id='statusSelect' onchange='myChangeHandler(this)'><option value='Suggested'>Select</option><option value='accept'>Accept</option><option value='reject'>Reject</option><option value='terminated'>Terminated</option></select></td>"
    print "</TABLE>"
    from tabulate import tabulate
```

I added a custom column in the result above 'New Status' in which we can select the new status that we want to assign to the record.

I want to write a code that can be used to update the database. The query is:

```
"UPDATE NewIssueOpinion " & _
"SET Status = '" & Status & "' " & _ #Getting Status using getformvalue.
"WHERE OpinionID = " & OpinionID & ";"     #How can we select the Opinion ID value from the result displayed from code1.
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db1.cursor()

SQLQuery = ("SELECT  I.OpinionID,
                     I.TimeStamp,
                     I.Strategy,
                     I.ExpectedTradingPrice,
                     I.ExpectedDate,
                     I.CPAMAnalyst,
                     I.Conviction,
                     I.Status,
                     N.DebtTicker,
                     N.InstrumentType,
                     N.ExpectedMaturity,
                     N.OrderSize,
                     N.Allocation
                 From [CpamTestAugustTestSteve].[dbo].[NewIssueOpinion] I
                 INNER JOIN [CpamTestAugustTestSteve].[dbo].[NewIssue] N ON I.NewIssueID = N.NewIssueID
                 WHERE N.ExpectedIssueDate >= GetDate()-30
                     AND I.Status = 'Suggested' AND I.Active = 1;")

#Execute the SQL command
cursor.execute(SQLQuery)


#Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.
results=cursor.fetchall()
y = len(results)
#define function
def Review():
    cursor.close()
    cursor = db1.cursor()
    for result in results: 
        my_OpinionID = result[1] 
        my_StatusID = result[14] 
        cursor.execute('UPDATE [CpamTestAugustTestSteve].[dbo].[NewIssueOpinion] SET Status = ? WHERE OpinionID = ?', (my_StatusID, my_OpinionID))
        db1.commit()
        cursor.close()
        db1.close()    
location.reload()
print "<br> <br>"
print "<body2>"
print "<form method='post' onclick='return Review();'>"
print "<div> <input type='Submit' class= 'submitbutton' value='Submit' /> </div> <br> <br>"
print "</form>"
if  not cursor.rowcount:
    print "<b> <mark> NO RECORDS FOUND!!</mark> </b>"
else:
    print "<TABLE>"
    print "<tablebody>"
    print"<tr>"
    print "<tr><th>S.No</th><th>OpinionID</th> <th>TimeStamp</th> <th>Strategy</th> <th>ExpectedTradingPrice</th> <th>ExpectedDate</th> <th>CPAMAnalyst</th> <th>Conviction</th> <th>Status</th> <th>DebtTicker</th> <th>InstrumentType</th> <th>ExpectedMaturity</th> <th>OrderSize</th> <th>Allocation</th><th>New Status</th>"
    for p in range(y):
        print "<tr><td>%s</td>" %(p+1)
        for q in range(len(results[p])):
            r= results[p][q]   
            print "<td> %s </td>" % (r)
    print "<td><select id='statusSelect'><option value='Suggested'>Select</option><option value='Accepted'>Accept</option><option value='rejected'>Reject</option><option value='terminated'>Terminated</option></select></td>"
    print "</TABLE>"
    from tabulate import tabulate                    
print "</body2>"


db1.commit()
```

The page is reloading when i click the submit button, but the database is not being updated. Not sure what went wrong!

Comment: Hi Addy. I know you will find here a lot of people who like to help other people in distress, but all are too lazy to write a whole program for you. If you edit your post by adding the code you've used so far and the parts that are problematic or missing, it may be different (and the downvotes will stop)

Comment: Thanks a lot Ettore, :) I have update the question to add the code. I really appreciate your response to help me get better help/response. I'm new to Stackoverflow too. Till now I only used it to do research thought existing questions, recently I started asking questions. Still figuring out the best way to do that.

Comment: Readers do want to help here, but being new to a community is obviously no excuse for begging volunteers for free work. Understanding that something is only urgent for the poster, and for no-one else at all, is important.

Comment: Thanks Halfer.  Not sure how a request for knowledge sharing can be interpreted as begging!!

Comment: @EttoreRizza If you want people to write code for you.... pay them... It's not the purpose of this site to have other people write your code for you.

Comment: @eandersson Did I say the opposite somewhere? :/

Comment: @EttoreRizza The wording of your sentence puts the blame on the people at Stackoverflow that are going out of their way to help. You could have just stopped after "like to help other people in distress", and you would have a perfectly positive sentence, instead of adding the completely unnecessary "lazy" part.

Comment: In the end people shouldn't expect someone else to write a whole program for you. There are pages where you can pay people to code for you.

Comment: @eandersson I'd answered that this "lazy" was a joke lost in translation, maybe inappropriate in English, but curiously the message disappeared.

Comment: I'm sorry that my post has caused so much of trouble. I'm really learning to write me questions in a better way. I really appreciate the constructive feedback.

Comment: @AddyB don't worry. I think the section [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will bring you many answers. Among the elements not mentioned: a small upvote when someone answers correctly does not hurt, and obviously a click on "accept" when the answer is very good. It's frustrating to write code that works without any feedback.

Comment: I'm upvoting the answers, but it seems that i need a 15+ reputation for my vote to be displayed.  They are storing my feedback but not showing.
I'm trying all the answers I'm getting here, but my code still hasn't worked yet. May be there is something missing. I keep updating my code based on the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

2 points here:

cur.fetchall returns a tuple of tuple. `results[0][0]` will be the *OpinionID* for the first row in your data returned by the query. `results[1][0]` will be the *OpinionID* for the second etc. `results [0][7]` will be the *Status* for the first row, etc.

DO NOT built queries using Python's string concatenation. Using the safe method.

```
my_first_OpinionID = results[0][0]
my_first_statusID = results[0][7]  
cur.execute("UPDATE NewIssueOpinion SET Status = ? WHERE OpinonID = ?", (my_first_OpinionID, my_first_statusID))
```

You may find these links useful:

```
<http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/>  
<http://bobby-tables.com/python>  
<http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_sqlite_in_python_tutorial.html>
```

Comment: I believe, the code will read opinion ID and Status ID in the first row only, I want to be able to perform this for all the rows that are displayed as result.

Comment: How would you normally read a tuple or list? `with result in results: my_OpinionID = result[0], my_StatusID[7]` etc. In my answer, the first index is the *row*, the second index is the *location in the row*.

Comment: P.S. Don't forget to commit your transaction when you update!

Comment: I understand but the data is dynamic. Number of rows in the result is not fixed. What should be done in such scenarios?

Comment: 2 ways. (1) Loop! `for result in results: my_OpinionID = result[0], my_StatusID = result[7], cur.execute("cur.execute("UPDATE NewIssueOpinion SET Status = ? WHERE OpinonID = ?", (my_OpinionID, my_statusID))")` and (2) executemany - see they links I have provided, they explain much better than I could about how to use executemany (but it is worth reading about as it's much more efficient than a loop)

Comment: I have updated the code to include the for loop. The function is defined is working but the database is not getting updated.

Comment: `my_StatusID = result[14]` is wrong. You don't have 14 return values. If you look at my answer, `I.Status` is at `my_StatusID = result[7]`. It's not updating the database because it's not matching any records.

Comment: My result has 14 columns. 

1. S.No 2. OpinionID 3.TimeStamp 4.Strategy 5.ExpectedTradingPrice 6.ExpectedDate 7.CPAMAnalyst 8.Conviction 9.Status 10.DebtTicker 11.InstrumentType 12.ExpectedMaturity 13.OrderSize 14.Allocation 15.New Status

S.No is a a new column added just to number the records.
New Status is a custom column in which we will choose the new status. The new status will replace the existing status in 9.Status

Comment: In that case you have `(my_OpinionID, my_StatusID)` the wrong way around - you are currently looking `WHERE OpinionID = NewStatus`. If you swap them to `(my_StatusID, my_OpinionID)` they will match.

Comment: You are right! I updated the code and ran it, but it still doesn't update the database.

Answer (score 0):

for result in cursor.execute(SQLQuery, multi=True):
   if result.with_rows:

same here , last time i tried to connect to db and print the results i uses that